# Renamed belongs_to association, it currently can't find the associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My user.location is returning nil currently.

My model looks like:

```
# id
# user_location_id
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location, class_name: "UserLocation"
end

user = User.find(1)
user.location.id # returns nil
```

Do I have to tell me model how to find the association in the UserLocation model?

Comment: what is the foreign_key to connect `user` and `user_location` table?

Comment: How can `user.location.id` this be nil, if association is malformed, `user.location` is nil..what do you get for `user.location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you have `user_location_id` as foreign_key to `user` table.
You can add it to you association.

```
belongs_to :location, class_name: "UserLocation", foreign_key: "user_location_id"
```

I hope this help you.